# using library inside python function

Tags: python, pandas

Problem: Importing an python file (EDA.py) into a jupyter notebook.The python file uses pandas and has an "Import pandas as pd" in it. But in Jupyter I get the error that pd is not defined.

Python file:

<EDA.py>

```
def eda_df(df):
    import pandas as pd
    print('=================Unique Values============================')
    unique_series = df.apply(pd.Series.nunique).sort_values()
    print(unique_series)
```

Jupyter Notebook:

```
    import EDA
    train = pd.read_csv(r'.\kaggle\housing\house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques\train.csv')
    eda_df(train)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-269-86ee9695b171> in <module>
----> 1 eda_df(train)

~\iCloudDrive\Adnan PC\Data Science\Jupyter NB\EDA.py in eda_df(df)
     13     print('Features missing more than 40% data: ',len(missing_data_list))
     14     print(missing_data_list)
---> 15     print('=================Unique Values============================')
     16     unique_series = df.apply(pd.Series.nunique).sort_values()
     17     unique_list = unique_series[unique_series<15].index.to_list()

NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
```

Comment: Did you `import pandas as pd`? Can you include that in your code?

Comment: See [modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules)

Comment: "tried entering `import pandas as pd` in the function" - this is exactly the correct way to import the library (it's more pythonic to import everything at the top of the file, but this also works)

Comment: I added import pandas as pd in the .py file (both in the function and above). but still get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to import pandas as pd:

```
import pandas as pd

def eda_df(df):
    unique_series = df.apply(pd.Series.nunique).sort_values()
    return (unique_series)
```

Comment: I'm not sure the code you think is being executed is the actual code that is being executed. Please post the exact stack trace (full exception) in the question (not in a comment), so we can see exactly what's going on. Remember to indent it with four spaces so the whitespace doesn't collapse; that can be done by first pasting the copy of the stack trace, then selecting the pasted stack trace, and then pressing Ctrl+K.

Comment: My jupyter notebook wasn't updating and was using the old file somehow. Thanks it works now.